# What is the distribution of the sum of n pareto-distributed random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If we have $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ that are all pareto($\alpha, \beta$)-distributed and independent, and we define $Y_i=-a_iX_i$, where $a_i$ is a positive constant for all i, what is the distribution of $Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$?

Below is my thought, but before reading this I hope there is a more "simple/direct" way of calculating this to also obtain scale/shape parameters.

We need to know what the distribution is for individual $Y_i$ and the sum of them. Regardring the sum-part I found a "Characterization Theroem" on wikipedia (pareto-distribution) that says that
$X_1+...+X_n$ is Pareto-distributed if $\text{min}\{X_1,...X_n\}$ is independent of $\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{\text{min}\{X_1,...X_n\}}$. But if this is true, what is the shape and scale parameter?
And how can we adopt this to our setup, where we also have the postive constants $a_i$?

Comment: I believe you've misread [this subsection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#A_characterization_theorem) of the Wikipedia article.  I read it as saying that if $\ X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\ $ are independent and identically distributed and $\ M=\min_i\big(X_i\big)\ $ and $\ \frac{\sum_i X_i}{M}\ $ are independent, then *the common distribution* of all the $\ X_i\ $ must be Pareto. I don't think it tells you anything about the distribution of their sum ( except that it must be a *convolution* of Pareto distributions).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But what what is the distribution then?

Comment: You can say that $Y_i$ is negative.  If $\alpha>2$ and the $a_i$ are well behaved then there will probably be a central limit theorem result for the limiting distribution of a suitably rescaled and relocated $\sum Y_i$  as $n$ increases.  So you should not expect the sum to have a Pareto distribution (with a monotonic density on its support)

Comment: It is because in the paper “Sharp Probability Tail Estimates for Portfolio Credit Risk” (27) on page 8, I really struggling to see how they have obtained the resultat with pareto

Answer (score 2):

The sum will not be a Pareto distribution, but still a so-called $\textbf{regularly varying }$ distribution.

We say that a univariate random variable $X$ is regularly varying if $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\mathbb P[|X|>xt]}{\mathbb P[|X|>x]}=t^{-\alpha}$$ which means that its tails will look similar to a Pareto distribution with index $\alpha$.

Such functions can be described using [Karamata's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function)

You can find more exact computations for the distribution of sums of Pareto variables in [this thesis](https://isfa.univ-lyon1.fr/medias/fichier/thesis-nguyen-derniere-version_1487168082027-pdf?ID_FICHE=295938&INLINE=FALSE) (download link).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to look at this thesis